# How to make a div appear over there

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs. I would like to position one div over the other and have it appear over it. I am able to position the div but how can I make it such that background of the div is not visible or should I control the background visibility.

....


...

[image]

Comment: If possible provide your code so we can easily identify what will be the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use background color and you can do one more thing that is while showing the upper div reduce the opacity of below div or just hide it or you can make overlay on which put the upper div so background div will not be visible. So many ways are already present to do such thing it depends upon you need.

Comment: I am aiming at making a slide-able side panel which is why I don't want to hide the background just control the visibility of the upper div.To make it more obvious. Can you please tell me what css properties should I look in to. I am using bootstrap for the design

Comment: You mean to say that a div will slide from left/right side on other div am i right?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I am looking for

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal bro you have to put background: Color you need;  Ex: background:#ffffff; which is white color. Put on sliding div and the below div will not visible. thy it and let me know so i can give you more suggestion if required.

Comment: Thanks alot i m glad to solve your problem any thing else you want i m here enjoy.